# Google Cloud Vision Search Product Python Client - How to return more than 10 results?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-python

Following the Google doc example I have this code:

```
def get_similar_products_uri(
    project_id, location, product_set_id, product_category, image_uri, filter
):
    image_annotator_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    image_source = vision.types.ImageSource(image_uri=image_uri)
    image = vision.types.Image(source=image_source)

    product_set_path = product_search_client.product_set_path(
        project=project_id, location=location, product_set=product_set_id
    )
    product_search_params = vision.types.ProductSearchParams(
        product_set=product_set_path,
        product_categories=[product_category],
        filter=filter,
    )
    image_context = vision.types.ImageContext(
        product_search_params=product_search_params
    )

    response = image_annotator_client.product_search(image, image_context=image_context)

    results = response.product_search_results.results
    return results
```

I have been trying to get 25 results instead of 10 but could not find a solution using the python client

I think I need to use a Feature

```
    #features = [{"type": vision.enums.Feature.Type.PRODUCT_SEARCH, "max_results": 25}]
```

but then I did not know how to use it.
It seems that this would work for `annotate_image` but it is not obvious to me how it works with `product_search`.

EDIT: 
link to the documentation I followed:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/searching?hl=cs

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide link for a doc, which you have used?

Comment: here it is: https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/searching?hl=cs

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/), where you can  find example of features option in response and also check this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548552/google-cloud-vision-web-detection-api-returns-only-10-responses) post on

Comment: Thanks @muscat but I still have issues. I could find a lot of resources on how to use features with `client.annotate_image` or `client.face_detection` but none with `image_annotator_client.product_search`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is using `max_results` directly while calling `product_search`

```
    response = image_annotator_client.product_search(
        image, image_context=image_context, max_results=25
    )
```

I could not find the documentation for this method I just guessed it by looking at the documentation of other methods such as: https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-vision/latest/Google/Cloud/Vision/V1p3beta1/ImageAnnotatorClient.html#document_text_detection